# Issue in R Environment

Tags: linear-programming

I am having issue in R environment, while running , no variables are coming!

I am trying this code:
`a=10 b=15 a+b`

While running this, a and b is not displayed in environment section. Despite clearing environment and closing the file and restarting, the problem persists.
How to set it right?